# Canonical-or-best data type to store a Flake ID in PostgresSQL for two query patterns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-13

I want to generate and write [128-bit k-ordered Flake IDs](https://github.com/boundary/flake) to a column from clients connected to my PostgreSQL database. These IDs are essentially a large globally-unique numbers that grow with time, similar to a monotonically increasing ID but without any coordination.

The two most common query patterns would look this:

- Sort by the Flake ID `SELECT * ORDER BY flake_id`
- Group by another column, and then select the maximum Flake ID in each group. `SELECT max(flake_id) GROUP BY some_other_column`

There seem to be a few possible ways to do this:

- `bigint` with two columns. Simple to order by, but unclear how to select maximum across two words after a group-by.
- `bytea` with 16 bytes.
- `bit(n)` where `n=128`
- `uuid` happen to be 128-bit, and testing yields ORDER BY results, but there is no `max` function that can be applied to it
- encoded as a string, and stored in `text` haven't tested it but a `max` function seems nonsensical unless it uses a lexicographic order. It also seems a bit dirty to use a string to encode what is order-able on its own numerically.

There's a bit of choice paralysis in the options and how they interact with indexes to perform the above query patterns most efficiently.

I am looking for insight into the ideal data-type considering the above query patterns, and how it would interact with the relevant indexes.

Comment: FYI, there are other numerical pseudo-random identifier generating algorithms that fit into the `BIGINT` data type, such as [Snowflake IDs](https://github.com/twitter-archive/snowflake), which will likely give you the same level of assurance. This is one that [Twitter has been using](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2010/announcing-snowflake) for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with two `bigint`s, create a composite type for `flake_id`:

```
CREATE TYPE pair (a bigint, b bigint);
```

Your first query then can remain as it is, and your second query could be rewritten to

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (some_other_column)
       flake_id
ORDER BY some_other_column, flake_id DESC;
```

But why don't you use the obvious data type `numeric`?

Comment: >But why don't you use the obvious data type numeric?


Because I didn't notice it was variable length! This is the exact reason I asked, for things I didn't know about Postgres that fit neatly into this problem.